# Error received while deploying code to Pixhawk4 from Simulink

Tags: simulink, hardware-interface, px4

I am trying to run an example Simulink model provided by Mathworks, but while deploying the model to the Pixhawk flight controller, I am receiving the following error:

```
Error(s) encountered while building "px4demo_uORBReadWrite":
### Failed to generate all binary outputs.
Caused by:
Validation error(s): 
### Validating other build tools ...
Unable to locate build tool "GNU PX4 Archiver": echo
```

I have followed all the steps to configure the hardware properly, except the last part where I was not able to receive the accelerometer data too. The error received while testing the connection at that time was:

```
Error reading data from the serial port. Operation timed out before requested data was received.
```

Can someone explain why I am having this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add info on that serial port the error mentions? What is it used for? What settings are you using and how do you set them?

Comment: I have connected the px4 using the usb. I have checked and its the COM3 port. Before the test, the same port was used to upload the firmware, and there were no problems with that.

Comment: I would double-check if the firmware is correctly installed. It seems nothing is listening on the other side of the connection

Comment: Regarding your first issue: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/453589-unable-to-locate-build-tool-gnu-px4-archiver-echo